# Do we have technology to ethically measure the changes of interstitial space in sleeping humans?

Tags: sleep

Lulu Xie et al write in their paper [Sleep Drives Metabolite Clearance from the Adult Brain](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/342/6156/373):

> Using real-time assessments of tetramethylammonium diffusion and two-photon imaging in live mice, we show that natural sleep or anesthesia are associated with a 60% increase in the interstitial space

Do we have technology to do the similar measurements in humans and not only in mice? Have those measurements been done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [It is possible to extract samples of interstitial fluid in humans.](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fphar.2016.00216)
- [The method has been described in detail.](http://www.jlr.org/content/41/8/1317.long)
- Is it ethically permissible to extract the entire contents of the interstitial space? No. It is vital for survival.

Technically, it seems possible to perform the procedure before and after sleep. I am not sure if this has been done though. To what extent this is an invasive procedure I do not know, but it appears to involve surgery.

- [In addition, *local* interstitual fluid pressure (IFP) can be
  measured in humans under anesthesia.](http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/61/17/6400?ijkey=e283201fdd4d53ba616e2e028728d929669b9c09&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha)

Both methods pose ethical challenges and it appears that these methods are relevant in clinical settings, where the cost-to-benefit analysis would suggest a benefit to the patient.